# How can I get the current username - USING MY CODE BELOW IN ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the current username of whoever made changes on a table?  A button?

```
private string GetCurrentUserName()
    {

        return Utilities.CurrentUsername();

    }
```

UTILITIES:

```
   public static string CurrentUsername()
    {
        string[] data = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\\' });
        string retVal = data[1];

        return retVal;

    }
```

Comment: What does this even mean?  You need to clarify more

Comment: FWIW, you can just use `.Split('\\');` (`Split` takes a `params char []`)

Comment: I have a code:
public static string CurrentUsername()
{
    string[] data = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\\' });
    string retVal = data[1];

    return retVal;
}

How can I use this on .net to get the current username for whoever making changes on a table?  What tool I should use from .net?

Comment: How can I get the current date and time from this code?  DateTime currentDateAndTime = SomeMagicalMethodThatDoesNotExist();

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to changes on a database table, you will need to track the user who last updated each record in the table itself.  I typically use an update_user and update_dt column in every table for his purpose.  I make sure every update, insert, and delete update this columns with the user and date/time of the update.  You can also have a pair of create_user and create_dt columns to maintain row creation.

I think you need to clarify what you mean in your question however.  Getting the last update user of a button doesn't make any sense, unless you store each time the button is clicked somewhere.

Comment: Cody I already have a trigger, I just need to extract who are the users?